# Why is my Allegro 5 map editor so slow? What could I change to make it faster?

Tags: c++, allegro5

I am creating an Allegro 5 map editor with C/C++ and I need help with it. When I run it, it works fine until I place some bitmaps on the screen. After 4-5 bitmaps are placed on the screen, the program starts to get horribly slow, making the editor almost impossible to use.

**Here's the code:**

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

//CLASS DEFINITION SECTION


class T_center
{
public:
    //place
    int p;
    int y;
    //place bound y up, x left, y down, x right
    int pbyu;
    int pbxl;
    int pbyd;
    int pbxr;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *img;
};

const int tileamount = 196;
T_center tile[tileamount];
int height = 700;
int width = 700;
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;
ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *queue;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *curr;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *ground;

//FUNCTION DECLARATION SECTION


void func_start_system();
void func_start_tiles(int tilesize, T_center *tile, int tilearray, int xsize);
void func_start_variables();
void func_detect_mouse_move(T_center *tile, int tilearray);

//THE TOOL ITSELF

int main()
{
    al_init();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_image_addon();
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    ground = al_load_bitmap("grass.jpg");
    func_start_system();
    func_start_tiles(25, tile, tileamount, tileamount);
    func_start_variables();
    al_flip_display();
    func_detect_mouse_move(tile, tileamount);
}






//FUNCTION DEFINITION SECTION

void func_start_system()
{
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();
}

void func_start_tiles(int tilesize, T_center *tile, int tilearray, int xsize)
{
    int xcount = 0;
    int tile_x = tilesize;
    int tile_y = tilesize;
    int y_count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tilearray; i++)
    {
        if (xcount == 14)
        {
            xcount = 0;
            tile_y = tile[i-1].pbyd + tilesize;
            tile_x = tilesize;
        }
        tile[i].p = tile_x, tile[i].y = tile_y, tile[i].pbxl = tile_x - tilesize, tile[i].pbxr = tile_x + tilesize, tile[i].pbyu = tile_y - tilesize, tile[i].pbyd = tile_y + tilesize;
        tile_x = tile[i].pbxr + tilesize;
        printf("%i, %i, left: %i\n", tile[i].p, tile[i].y, tile[i].pbxl);
        xcount++;
    }
}

void func_start_variables()
{
    curr = al_load_bitmap("grass.jpg");
    display = al_create_display(width, height);
    queue = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
}

void func_detect_mouse_move(T_center *tile, int tilearray)
{
    bool a = true;
    while (a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tilearray; i++)
            if (tile[i].img != NULL)
                al_draw_bitmap(tile[i].img, tile[i].pbxl, tile[i].pbyu, 0);
        al_wait_for_event(queue, &ev);
        if (ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilearray; i++)
                if (ev.mouse.x >= tile[i].pbxl && ev.mouse.x < tile[i].pbxr && ev.mouse.y >= tile[i].pbyu && ev.mouse.y < tile[i].pbyd)
                {
                    al_draw_tinted_bitmap(curr, al_map_rgb(100, 60, 60), tile[i].pbxl, tile[i].pbyu, 0);
                    al_flip_display();
                }
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        }
        if (ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
        {
            if (ev.mouse.button & 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tilearray; i++)
                {
                    if (ev.mouse.x >= tile[i].pbxl && ev.mouse.x < tile[i].pbxr && ev.mouse.y >= tile[i].pbyu && ev.mouse.y < tile[i].pbyd)
                        tile[i].img = curr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I might be doing something really stupid when it comes to drawing things on the screen, but I have no idea of *what* I am doing wrong.

**Do you have any tips for me?**

Comment: Please remove C tag , this is C++

Comment: Whoops! I removed the C tag. It really made no sense to have a C tag here.

Comment: Have you used a profiler? If you don't have access to one, you can also use timers before and after different sections of the code to determine what the slow down is.

It shouldn't make your performance super slow so it isn't the answer, but you can do tile lookup in your detect mouse move much faster. There are a number of methods of detecting the tile you are over. In grid based maps, you can calculate the position of the cursor very easily. For arbitrary maps, you can use a quad tree to quickly find if it is over a tile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating and loading bitmaps before a display is created. This bitmaps reside on system memory instead of video memory. The reason they don´t use video memory is that Allegro has no other place to put them because the display is not loaded first.

You need to start the display as soon as possible and then load the bitmaps inside it. Or, as an alternative, you can load them to system memory and then, after you create your display, you copy them to the video memory using [`al_convert_bitmaps`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/graphics.html#al_convert_bitmaps). Keep in mind you need to do that after a valid display is created.

My recommendation? Move display creation from `func_start_variables()` to a better place: Inside your main, right after `al_init()`.

The reason memory bitmaps are slow, in case you would like to know, is that everytime you need to draw they have to be copied by the cpu to the graphic card, then it discards them. A video bitmap stays on the GPU so it is only a matter of displaying the contents already on memory. No copy operation is done by the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for The answer! I knew it was a stupid error of mine :P. Also I loved your explanation about The bitmaps. I have already had a problem like this before but I forgot what I should initialize first: display or bitmaps. :)

Comment: No problem!, That's a hard one to catch if it never ever happened before to you ;)

Comment: Hi! I am not sure if it's alright to ask another question here, but just out of curiosity: When I press, say, the P key, or any other key in the keyboard, some blocks start to appear out of nowhere in the screen. I find this to be fascinating. Can you think of any reason for this "glitch" to happen?

Comment: Well this is not the correct place to write a new question, you just write a new one. However, I can tell you that from the code you provided I cannot see where is that functionality of the keyboard found. So cannot say what caused it. Remember comments are for clarification of question points and for suggestion for the answer, not a place to make back-and-fort talking as it pollutes the site's appearance.